# MPD Installation on Centos 6.3

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, centos-6, mpd

I am in the process of migrating from Ubuntu Server over to CentOS.  While I can easily configure MPD as a system wide service on Ubuntu, I am having difficulty with CentOS.  Can anyone recommend a step-by-step to do this?  The Wiki is confusing.  Also, I will be running MPD in conjuction with Pulseaudio.  If anyone needs help with the Ubuntu MPD install, I can provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this blog post and you can't go wrong:
http://nixmeal.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/configuring-mpd-with-ncmpcpp-under-rhelcentos-6/

Comment: I heard rpmforge is deprecated.